# charpoly and rank of a projection

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is a projection on $\mathbb{R}^n$ so I know  $A^2=A$ and eigen values are $1,0$ given that $\dim Ker(A-I)=m$ then what is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and rank of $A$?

I am not getting what is the use of the operator $A-I$ and the dimension of its null space.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projections are diagonalizable - you can take bases of Ker($A$) and Im($A$) and put them together to give a diagonalizing basis for $A$.

Since $\mathrm{Ker}(A-I)$ is $m$-dimensional, $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ of geometric multiplicity $m$. Since $A$ is diagonalizable, it also has algebraic multiplicity $m$.

So $0$ must have algebraic multiplicity $n-m$, and you get the characteristic polynomial $$\chi_A(t) = t^{n-m}(t-1)^m.$$

Answer (score 1):

A is diagonalizable as the minimal polynomial is $x(x-1)$(Considering that $A$ is not a scalar multiple of $I$ or $0$). So dim$(A)$+dim$(A-I)=n$.Thus the characteristic polynomial is

$$p(x)=(x-1)^mx^{n-m}$$